# Area chart looks flat because Y Axis starts from 0

Tags: highcharts

Area chart looks flat due to the fact that Y axis always starts from 0 in compare to a line chart which in the same data uses some sort of auto-fit.

[Plunkr](https://jsfiddle.net/v56hzusg/)

I would like to have similar auto-fit on the area chart that works on line chart as default.

```
(Using yAxis[0].setExtremes is not an option really).
```

Is there any configuration to do so?

Comment: i think both are correct. both charts start at (0,15k) because the y axis values are so high so it don't show 0 on graph, it cant show from 0 to 15000 in one step
increase height of your graph and see it,you will see more details

Comment: @AhmedSunny - out of the same settings and dataset AreaChart starts from 0 and LineChart starts from 15000. I would like to have AreaChart starting from same point as LineChart (when based on the same dataset)

Comment: area chart supposed to work like this, but you can give min:15000 in y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by setting `xAxis.min` property like that:

```
  yAxis: {
    min: 10000,
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Layfnuz4/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min

---

The second approach is to set `plotOptions.area.threshold`

```
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      threshold: 10000,
      marker: {
        enabled: false,
        symbol: 'circle',
        radius: 2,
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r7qc1jpk/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.threshold

---

**EDIT**

Automatic approach: set `series.area.softThreshold = true` as line series has.

```
  series: [{
    softThreshold: true,
    name: 'Data',
    data: data
  }]
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8uj3kz4a/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.softThreshold

Comment: this unfortunately means that we need to set the minimum point manually so iterate over all points to find the lowest. I am rather looking for solution that will adjust automatically (like LineChart does)

Comment: I forgot to write you the best automatic solution, check the edited answer;)

Comment: YES - softThreshold is what I need. Thanks.